# POWERBI - Excel imported table not filtering on shared filter table

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my PowerBi report I have a shared table that I use to filter all the data tables, based on a dimension:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/WbLdtcy.png]

Both the Calendar and Global Dimension 1 Code, filter the data tables:

1. Sales Invoice Line [SQL]
2. General Ledger Line [SQL]
3. Service Invoice Line [SQL]
4. Goals [EXCEL]

On all the tables the Dimension filtering works as expected, only on the Excel GOALS table, this does not work. I checked the data field and spelling, these are all matching. Do you have any idea, why this filter does not work.

Without a filter this is an example of the visual (table is only for debugging).
The full lines come from the GOALS table, while the dotted lines come from the SQL tables.

[image: No filtering]

When I press a Business Unit filter it changes to this:

[image: Filtered]

You can see that the SQL tables are clearly filtered, while the GOALS table isn't.

Both tables have the same format and the fields are trimmed to make sure there are no hidden spaces. I added an empty line for each year in the goals, because the splicer automatically adds a blank option. Before I added this it also didn't work.

GOALS:
[image: Goals data]

GD1C:
[image: Global Dimension 1 Code]

Comment: are the join columns between `Goals` and `Global Dimension 1 Code` consistent? I.e. same data type, same values formatting (e.g. either 001234 or 1234 but not mix?) Also - `Calendar` does not filter `Goals` based on the picture you provided, is this intentional?

Comment: @Stachu I changed the original post to include the data entries. They have the same data types and are formatted equally. They are also all trimmed to ensure there are no random spaces. The calendar is not used in this case, because I filter it later using measures:

https://i.imgur.com/7zwjN3V.png
https://i.imgur.com/ksuf0zO.png